# Yii2 actions have capitalization problems

Tags: yii2

I have this rule in my urlmanager

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```

and this action

```
public function actionDefaultTop()
{
   return $this->render('app_launch');
}
```

This shows a 404

I want to also be able to have a parameter in my actions with this rule

```
'<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:[\d]+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

however, i can't even first step where my action are camel cased. How do i go about combining the two rules in my url manager?

Comment: You should use `'<controller[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',` as rule and call this action as `https://example.com/my-controller/default-top`.

Comment: This too `'<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:[\d]+>' => '<controller>/<action>'` should work for https://example.com/my-controller/default-top/3 right?

Comment: Nope. You need `'<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:[\d]+>' => '<controller>/<action>'` for such URLs.

Comment: That works. How can i get the id part of the rul i mean the actual parameter `Yii::$app->controller->action->id;` this gives the action id and not the parameter after slash.

Comment: This worked `$id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');` thanks

Comment: I suggest to take a moment and read documentation, these are really basic questions: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers